# How to display blog post by category in nav menu?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Any idea how to list blog post by category in nav menu?

For example: https://www.purelyb.com/ (the second navigation bar)

Is there any plugins out there or required custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by going to Appearance>Menus and on the sidebar you'll see "Custom link", "Pages", and "Categories". Just check the box under the category you want and add it to the menu.